# Specflow plus evaluation version attaching a screenshot

Tags: c#, specflow

Is it possible to attach the screenshot in the report 
with an c#, specflow auto framework.

I have included report template in 
.srprofile

As mentioned in https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/tutorial:-customising-reports/

But that didnt worked out for me!

Did anyone had luck with this?

Or any suggestions to use alternate reporting for screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

We have an example https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest which adds screenshots to the report. Have a look at it.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of SpecFlow and developer on SpecFlow+

Comment: Thank you, Thats the repo i referred following the link https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/tutorial:-customising-reports/
which i posted in the original question. Do we need specflow plus for the customising 
 the report and including the screenshot?

Comment: @Ram: Yes you  need SpecFlow+ for this.

Comment: @c32hedge: sorry, I forgot to add it. disclosure is now added.